# SQL : Test if a column has the "Not Null" property

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

Is there a simple query to return whether a specific column allows nulls?
I want to change this as part of a DB upgrade script.

Alternatively, is it better to just change it, even if its already set?

Edit : This is for SQL Server (needs to support 2000 or later)

Comment: You must tag this with an actual RDBMS you're using if you want an answer. Introspection on the database is not very well standardized in the real world.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Any particular RDBMS?

In SQL Server

```
use master

SELECT COLUMNPROPERTY( OBJECT_ID('dbo.spt_values'),'number','AllowsNull')
```

Or (more standard)

```
select IS_NULLABLE 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where TABLE_SCHEMA='dbo' 
      AND TABLE_NAME='spt_values' 
      AND COLUMN_NAME='number'
```

Comment: Sorry, I tagged it SQL, thought it would be more prominent

Comment: @Abort - You can have up to 5 tags! Which RDBMS are you actually using?

Comment: @Abort - SQL is the language. Do you mean SQL-Server? If so add another tag.

Comment: Thanks.  Both of these did the job.  I went with the first, as it returns an int (0/1) rather than 'Yes'/'No'